# How can i take a cut/commission in paypal?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, paypal

how can i take a cut/commission in paypal after user has paid amount and before receiver has got amount.

In my application I allow sellers to give some service to customers. When a customer pays $100 to seller then I need to cut 12.5% as commission.

How can I do that in Paypal. My Application is in rails.

Comment: Have you checked the [PayPal's Adaptive Payments API docs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/)?

Comment: Agree, what you need, specifically from the adaptive payments, is a chained payment: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-basicChainedPayment-curl-etc/